# More than one modals get stuck in loop, Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've recently been having a problem with modals in Bootsrap 3.

I'm working on a test website (not anything I would actually put on the web) and have 3 pictures (each in a `col-md-4`) next to each other, and I am planning on having one button centered under each picture which can be clicked for a modal to show up with more info.

I set up the first modal, which worked perfectly.
However, when I added the second one, I found that when you click either button, both modals show up on top of each other, (the second one first) and when you press "Back to home", it goes to the other modal.

You can only go back to home by pressing the "X" one or two times.

I am almost certain that this is due to my JavaScript in `<head>` being very incorrect, but I am not very good at JS and have no idea what I did wrong...

Here is the html so you can inspect my handiwork:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>space</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
          $("#chimechoModal").modal('show');
        });
      });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $(".btn").click(function(){
          $("#eeveeModal").modal('show');
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container custom-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:15px;"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
          <h1>Mini Pokedex</h1>
          <h4>Created by spaceman1980</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <hr>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/chimecho.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">    
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/eevee.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">   
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/james.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">   
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chimecho">
            Pokedex Entry
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="chimechoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="chimechoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="chimechoLabel">The Wind Chime Pokemon</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h5>
                    Chimecho makes its cries echo inside its hollow body. When this Pokémon becomes enraged, its cries result in ultrasonic waves that have the power to knock foes flying.
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to home</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
          <!-- Button trigger modal -->
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eevee">
            Pokedex Entry
          </button>

          <!-- Modal -->
          <div class="modal fade" id="eeveeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eeveeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                      <h5 class="modal-title" id="eeveeLabel">The Evolution Pokemon</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <h5>
                    Eevee has an unstable genetic makeup that suddenly mutates due to the environment in which it lives. Radiation from various stones causes this Pokémon to evolve.
                  </h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to home</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: if it is something wrong with your JS, can you please supply the code? Or even better, the whole website on a JSFiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Even though you are using inline javascript, there is no need to define the `<script>` tag twice

2) This line in your code says that whenever an element in your DOM with the class 'btn' is clicked it will perform a function (open a modal in your case). You are listening to both the 'btn' elements' click events.

```
 $(".btn").click(function(){
```

You can assign a different class to each button for each modal type. For example,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-chimecho" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chimecho">

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-eevee" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eevee">


     $(function(){
       $(".btn-chimecho").click(function(){
           $("#chimechoModal").modal('show');
         });
       $(".btn-eevee").click(function(){
           $("#eeveeModal").modal('show');
         });

     });

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This really helps

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're using `.btn` (a common class shared on both buttons) to trigger the modal. So when you click on any `.btn`, it fires both modals.

Either add a class/id or use the `data-target` attribute on your click handler to fire the appropriate modal, or since your button is right before the modal element in your html, you can just use a single click handler with `$('.btn')` and fire the modal via `$(this).next().modal()`.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>space</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $(".btn").on('click',function() {
        $(this).next().modal("show");
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container custom-container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12" style="height:15px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <img src="images/logo.png" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 text-right text-uppercase">
        <h1>Mini Pokedex</h1>
        <h4>Created by spaceman1980</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <hr>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/chimecho.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/eevee.png" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="images/james.jpg" style="width: 100%; height: auto;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chimecho">
                        Pokedex Entry
                    </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="chimechoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="chimechoLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="chimechoLabel">The Wind Chime Pokemon</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>
                                        Chimecho makes its cries echo inside its hollow body. When this Pokémon becomes enraged, its cries result in ultrasonic waves that have the power to knock foes flying.
                                    </h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to home</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#eevee">
                        Pokedex Entry
                    </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="eeveeModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="eeveeLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="eeveeLabel">The Evolution Pokemon</h5>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                            </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <h5>
                                        Eevee has an unstable genetic makeup that suddenly mutates due to the environment in which it lives. Radiation from various stones causes this Pokémon to evolve.
                                    </h5>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Back to home</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```